# Center a table on boundary between cells?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have the following table:

```
\documentclass[ebook]{memoir}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
First edition: & 2014 \\
Second edition: & 2015 \\
Third edition: & 2017 \\
\end{tabular}

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

center
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I want the table to center on the & and not on the table width. It'll be technically off-center but visually look better (the blank space will be above the 0).

Is there an easy way to do this without minipage and hand-adjusting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`eqparbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox)'s `\eqmakebox[<tag>][<align>]{<stuff>}` sets all `<stuff>` under the same `<tag>` in a box of the same width. Additionally one can specify `<align>`ment to suit your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eqparbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{ r | l }
    First edition: & 2014 \\
    \eqmakebox[widest][r]{Second edition:} & \eqmakebox[widest][l]{2015} \\
    Third edition: & 2017
  \end{tabular}

  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Since this process uses the `.aux` file, it requires at least two compilations with every change in `<stuff>` (the width of the box(es)).

Comment: This works perfectly and exactly what I was looking for. Running twice is no problem as I've a ToC and labels.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

[image]

```
    \documentclass[ebook]{memoir}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{0.8\linewidth}{>{\raggedleft}XX}
    First edition:  & 2014 \\
    Second edition: & 2015 \\
    Third edition:  & 2017 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{center}
    \end{tabularx}

    \end{document}

**Edit:**
Ups! At upload of codes I by mistake load the same code twice. The second one should be as in now the code above. With comparison of result of Werner and my solution I don't see any difference (above is Werner solution, below is my):

\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{ r | l }
    First edition: & 2014 \\
    \eqmakebox[widest][r]{Second edition:} & \eqmakebox[widest][l]{2015} \\
    Third edition: & 2017
  \end{tabular}

  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

\begin{tabularx}{.8\linewidth}{>{\raggedleft}XX}
First edition:  & 2014 \\
Second edition: & 2015 \\
Third edition:  & 2017 \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\end{document}[![enter image description here][2]][2]
```

Comment: This centers everything, but the 1 2 3 4 etc line was just for show; to show the misalignment.

Comment: well, your question is not very clear. your MWE already center table on the page. so, what should be centered?